# How to fetch data from DB on Chart.js using Laravel?

Tags: laravel, chart.js

I want to show data from database on chart and I have shown return response I need to fetch on chart but I don't know how to do that does anyone have an idea?

**Return response:**

```
[
  "Joylinkhk: 13,",
  "HorizonTechnologies: 2,",
  "Alahazrat: 9,",
  "j2w: 0,"
]
```

**Chart script:**

```
<script>
 
  var barChartData = {
    labels: ['Joylinhk', 'HorizonTechnologies','Alahazrat','j2w'],
    datasets: [{
      label: "",
      backgroundColor: window.chartColors.blue,
      data: [13, 2,9,0],
    }
              ]
  };
  window.onload = function() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
    window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: barChartData,
      options: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Project Report Chart'
        }
        ,
        tooltips: {
          mode: 'index',
          intersect: false
        }
        ,
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            stacked: true,
          }
                 ],
          yAxes: [{
            stacked: true
          }
                 ]
        }
      }
    }
   );
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do This more than one time
first of all you should Include Google Chart in Your Blade File

Let's See The controller function that return data to the chart
I make a function called `getAreaChart()`

```
public function getAreaChart():array {
        $data = DB::table('companies')->get();
        $array[]=['area','counts'];
        foreach ($data as $key=>$da):
            $array[++$key] = [Area::find($da->area)->area,intVal($da->count)];
        endforeach;
        return $array;
    }
```

for the function that return data to view and displayed in chart, I call the function and don't forget to json_encode the result

```
 public function home()
    {
        $array = $this->getAreaChart();
        return view('admin.home')->with('companies', json_encode($array));;
    }
```

in the blade file , I make a div with id pie_chart

```
<div id="pie_chart" style="width:510px; height:408px;background: transparent">
```

and the script should be like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var analytics = <?php echo $companies; ?>

        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart()
        {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(analytics);
            var options = {
                title : ''
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('pie_chart'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>
```

You can change the chart by change the value `corechart` see google chart doc
this is example that I follow
[Google Charts Docs](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart.html)

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
```

and this is the google charts types
[Google Charts Types](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery)

I hop that helpful ;)

> happy code